# Several top numbers in a column T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table called `_Invoice` in SQL Server 2016 - like this:

```
Company InvoiceNo
-----------------
10      1
10      2
10      3
20      1
20      2
20      3
20      4
```

I want to get the highest value from all companies.

Like this:

```
Company InvoiceNo
-----------------
10      3
20      3
```

I want this data to then update another table that is called `InvoiceSeries`
where the `InvoiceNo` is higher than the `NextNo` in `InvoiceSeries` table

I am stuck with getting the highest data from `InvoiceNo`:

```
UPDATE InvoiceSeries 
SET NextNo = -- Highest number from each company--
FROM InvoiceSeries ise
JOIN _Invoice i ON ise.InvoiceSeries = i.InvoiceSeries
WHERE i.InvoiceNo > ise.NextNo
```

Some example data:

```
Columns in InvoiceSeries    Columns in _Invoices    
    Company NextNo          Company         InvoiceNo
    10      9007            10              9008
    20      1001            10              9009
                            10              9010
                            10              9011
                            10              9012
                            20              1002
                            20              1003
                            20              1004
```

Comment: Your sample data includes Company = 20, InvoiceNo = 4.  However, your "highest value from all companies" table returns Company = 20, InvoiceNo = 3.  Is that intentional or an error?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for the HIGHEST common invoice number

**Example**

```
Select A.*
 From  YourTable A
 Join  (
        Select Top 1 with ties
               InvoiceNo
        From  YourTable
        Group By InvoiceNo
        Having count(Distinct Company) = (Select count(Distinct Company) From YourTable)
        Order  By InvoiceNo Desc
       ) B on A.InvoiceNo=B.InvoiceNo
```

**Returns**

```
Company  InvoiceNo
10       3
20       3
```

> **EDIT - Updated for comment**

```
Select company
      ,Invoice=max(invoiceno) 
 From  YourTable 
Group By company
```

Comment: I want the highest InvoiceNo from each Company so outputs should be  company 10 invoiceNo 3, company 20 and invoiceNo 4

Comment: @Rubiano Then a simple max() should do the trick   Select company,Invoice=max(invoiceno) From YourTable Group By company

Comment: The select statement works.SELECT Company, MAX(InvoiceNo) as 'InvoiceNo' FROM _Invoice GROUP BY Company. But I also want it to be used in the Update statement

Comment: I trided this BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE InvoiceSeries SET NextNo=(SELECT Company, MAX(InvoiceNo) as 'InvoiceNo' FROM _Invoice GROUP BY Company)
FROM  InvoiceSeries ise
JOIN _Invoice i ON ise.InvoiceSeries=i.InvoiceSeries
WHERE i.InvoiceNo>ise.NextNo

Comment: but then I get this error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes there will be a record in the Invoice Series table.

```
--Insert Sample Data
CREATE TABLE #_Invoice (Company INT, InvoiceNo INT)

INSERT INTO #_Invoice(Company, InvoiceNo)
VALUES 
    (10 , 1),
    (10 , 2),
    (10 , 3),
    (20 , 1),
    (20 , 2),
    (20 , 3),
    (20 , 4)

CREATE TABLE #InvoiceSeries(Company INT, NextNo INT)

INSERT INTO  #InvoiceSeries(Company, NextNo)
VALUES  
    (10, 1),
    (20 ,1)

UPDATE      s
SET         NextNo = MaxInvoiceNo
FROM        #InvoiceSeries s
INNER JOIN  (
    --Get the Max invoice number per company
    SELECT      Company, MAX(InvoiceNo) as MaxInvoiceNo
    FROM        #_Invoice
    GROUP BY    Company
) i on i.Company = s.Company
AND     s.NextNo < i.MaxInvoiceNo --Only join to records where the 'nextno' is less than the max

--Confirm results
SELECT * FROM #InvoiceSeries

DROP TABLE #InvoiceSeries
DROP TABLE #_Invoice
```